# Angular 6 - Property '$' does not exist on type 'Window'

Tags: jquery, angular

I am trying to use jQuery and jsGrid with my Angular 6 project, and it won't compile unless I comment offending part of code, and then once when it is compiled I comment and it works, but it gives error anyway. I am using Angular 6 CLI, IDE is Visual Studio Code, all latest versions. VS highlights jQuery alias i.e. $ sign as a problem

Here is structure.directive.ts (I have to comment whole ngOnInit to start server, then uncomment it):

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[structure]'
})
export class StructureDirective implements OnInit {

  clients = [
    { "Name": "Otto Clay", "Age": 25, "Country": 1, "Address": "Ap #897-1459 Quam Avenue", "Married": false },
    { "Name": "Connor Johnston", "Age": 45, "Country": 2, "Address": "Ap #370-4647 Dis Av.", "Married": true },
    { "Name": "Lacey Hess", "Age": 29, "Country": 3, "Address": "Ap #365-8835 Integer St.", "Married": false },
    { "Name": "Timothy Henson", "Age": 56, "Country": 1, "Address": "911-5143 Luctus Ave", "Married": true },
    { "Name": "Ramona Benton", "Age": 32, "Country": 3, "Address": "Ap #614-689 Vehicula Street", "Married": false }
  ];

  countries = [
    { Name: "", Id: 0 },
    { Name: "United States", Id: 1 },
    { Name: "Canada", Id: 2 },
    { Name: "United Kingdom", Id: 3 }
  ];

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    window.$(this.elementRef.nativeElement).jsGrid({
      width: "100%",
      height: "400px",

      inserting: true,
      editing: true,
      sorting: true,
      paging: true,

      data: this.clients,

      fields: [
        { name: "Name", type: "text", width: 150, validate: "required" },
        { name: "Age", type: "number", width: 50 },
        { name: "Address", type: "text", width: 200 },
        { name: "Country", type: "select", items: this.countries, valueField: "Id", textField: "Name" },
        { name: "Married", type: "checkbox", title: "Is Married", sorting: false },
        { type: "control" }
      ]
    })
  }
}
```

and here is index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Aug4</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsgrid/1.5.3/jsgrid.min.css" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsgrid/1.5.3/jsgrid-theme.min.css" />

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsgrid/1.5.3/jsgrid.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Error is:

```
Date: 2018-08-26T14:01:56.175Z - Hash: fb473e9c8d7de6bf4569 - Time: 224ms
4 unchanged chunks
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 52.1 kB [initial] [rendered]
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
ERROR in src/app/structure.directive.ts(26,12): error TS2339: Property '$' does not exist on type 'Window'.
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: I think you should import `jQuery` rather than accessing it from the `window` reference (see [here](https://medium.com/@swarnakishore/how-to-include-and-use-jquery-in-angular-cli-project-592e0fe63176)).

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40732787/how-to-add-jquery-to-window-object-when-using-angular-typescript-webpack - Another question is do you really need jquery when using angular, isn't the native Dom API enough? Your descision

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a problem with the typescript types not with angular. Run this command

```
npm install @types/jquery --save-dev
```

or if you are using yarn:

```
yarn add @types/jquery
```

And then add this in a type declaration file aka `somefile.d.ts`

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    $: JQueryStatic
   }
}
```

> This approach only makes the types available! You still have to import jquery somewhere.

alternatively you could import jquery. This will include the library itself and the types.

```
import * as $ from "jquery"
```

and use it without the window prefix.

Answer (score 0):

For the reference here is what I did (thanks to the Patrick):

```
npm install @types/jquery
```

and then in component:

```
declare var $: any;
declare var jsGrid: any;
```

Otherwise, there will be same error for jsGrid.